# Wait for browser to stop scrolling in protractor / selenium?

Tags: selenium, protractor

I'm running tests in protractor where we scroll an element into view, wait for it to be clickable, and then click it.

```
await scrollIntoView(this.locator.rowByName(name), this.browser);
await this.browser.wait(
  ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(this.locator.checkboxByName(name)),
  3000,
  `Waiting for checkbox for ${name} to be clickable.`);
await this.locator.checkboxByName(name).click();
```

Randomly this fails saying a different element would receive the click. The screenshots on failure show that the browser is not done scrolling. So, while the element is clickable, attempting to click it fails due to the in-progress scroll.

Is there a built-in way to wait for the browser to stop scrolling, like

```
// doesn't work but wish it did
await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.doneScrolling(browser), ... )
```

I can hack in a check where I record the scroll position, wait some time, check again, and repeat till doesn't change, but I'd prefer not to do that if there is already a way built in.

Comment: My guess is that it's within the viewport, it's just under some piece of UI from what you are describing. If the blocking piece of UI eventually disappears, you can wait on it to be invisible. You can also write a wrapper around click that attempts a click and eats exceptions until it succeeds or times out. I can't say that either are particularly elegant, but it's  probably what's available at this point.

Comment: This. I think that your trick here is to scroll even more than your element. So with an offset (say element is at position 10, you scroll to position 10+2), Guess that will help your case

Comment: waiting for an element to be clickable will be true even if it is not scrolled into view. `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` will be clickable when the page loads. Are you doing this because you want screenshots?